# How to get the optimal number of clusters from the clusGap function as an output?

Tags: r, list, output, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I have a data frame with 2 variables and I want to use the `clusGap` function to find the number of clusters that would be optimal to use. This code has a similar result:

```
library(cluster)    
x <- as.vector(runif(100, 0, 1))
y <- as.vector(runif(100, 0, 1))
df <- data.frame(x, y)
gap_stat <- clusGap(df, FUN = kmeans, nstart = n,
                    K.max = 10, B = 50)
gap_stat
```

Result:

```
Clustering Gap statistic ["clusGap"] from call:
clusGap(x = df, FUNcluster = kmeans, K.max = 10, B = 50, nstart = n)
B=50 simulated reference sets, k = 1..10; spaceH0="scaledPCA"
 --> Number of clusters (method 'firstSEmax', SE.factor=1): 1
          logW   E.logW           gap     SE.sim
 [1,] 2.569315 2.584217  0.0149021144 0.03210076
 [2,] 2.285049 2.284537 -0.0005116382 0.03231529
 [3,] 2.053193 2.033653 -0.0195399122 0.03282376
 [4,] 1.839085 1.835590 -0.0034952935 0.03443303
 [5,] 1.691219 1.708479  0.0172603348 0.03419994
 [6,] 1.585084 1.597277  0.0121935992 0.03440672
 [7,] 1.504763 1.496853 -0.0079104306 0.03422321
 [8,] 1.416176 1.405903 -0.0102731340 0.03371149
 [9,] 1.333721 1.323658 -0.0100626869 0.03245958
[10,] 1.253199 1.250366 -0.0028330498 0.03034140
```

As you can see in line 4, the optimal number of clusters is 1. I would like the function to have 1 as an output. I need the optimal number of outputs to be an object in the environment, such as `n` is 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically such information is somewhere directly inside the object, like `gap_stat$nc`. To look for it `str(gap_stat)` would typically suffice.

In this case, however, the above strategy isn't enough. But the fact that you can see your number of interest in the output, means that `print.clusGap` (because the class of `gap_stat` is clusGap) will show how to obtain this number. So, inspecting `cluster:::print.clusGap` leads to

```
maxSE(f = gap_stat$Tab[, "gap"], SE.f = gap_stat$Tab[, "SE.sim"])
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This may have been less transparent in the past, but you can actually specify the method directly:

```
nc <- maxSE(f         = gap_stat$Tab[,"gap"],
            SE.f      = gap_stat$Tab[,"SE.sim"],
            method    = "firstSEmax",
            SE.factor = 1)
```